# Identify a directory and move content with find in bash

Tags: bash, find

I want to move all the files of some specific directories to another one single directory called shp_all. 
The specific directories in question are all those that contain, among others, files with "shp" in their names. 
the directory looks like:

```
 -data
 --shp_all
 --d1
 --d2
   ...
 --dN
```

I managed to dinf a way to identify all the directories, among the `d1,...,dN` that have files  with name `"shp"`:

```
 find . -name '*shp*'
```

However, I don't know how to correctly use `exec` or `execdir` to take **all** the files in the same directory as the output and move them to `shp_all`

Here is what tried and did not work:

```
find . -name '*shp*'   -execdir mv '{}/*' shp_all ';'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one way to do this is the following (keeping in mind the recommendation above from Dave above to move the target directory out of the `find` path) :

```
mv $(find . -name "*shp*" -printf "%h\n" | uniq)/* ../shp_all/
```

Note, that will also move any subdirectories as well.  If you really only want files, you can add another level to only find `-type f`:

```
mv $(find $(find . -name "*shp*" -printf "%h\n" | uniq) -type f) ../shp_all/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small problem here, in that your target path `./shp_all/` is within the path you are searching. This will cause you trouble as files could be moved into the folder before the find gets round to searching the folder.
I would recommend moving that out for the duration of the file selection / move.
The following snippet should be run from within the `./data` folder you describe above.

```
mv ./shp_all ..
find . -name "*shp*" -exec mv {} ../shp_all/ \;
```

The `\;` at the end of the find is important to close the `-exec` otherwise the command will fail to execute.

Hope that helps.
Dave

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, your code will only move the files containging shp to shp_all, that is now outside the working directory. 
However, I would like to move **all** the files in the subdirectories, whenever that subdirectory contains at least one  file with 'shp' in its name

Comment: That is definitely more complicated!